# Is it possible to use Rails authenticate_with_http_token with Roda app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, roda

I made an API with Rails that authenticates using  `authenticate_with_http_token` method. This is working great.

The API uses [tus-ruby-server](https://github.com/janko/tus-ruby-server) for resumable file uploads. `Tus::Server` is a Roda app. I can use [hooks](https://github.com/janko/tus-ruby-server#hooks) to add authentication. It is working inside the Rails app (its endpoints are mounted in `routes.rb`).

Rails already provides `authenticate_with_http_token` which is a very well crafted implementation to authenticate via tokens. Is it possible to use this method somehow in the Roda app inside these hooks?

So far I couldn't succeed in doing so and I ended implementing a simpler way to read the header and parse the token that leaved me with a feeling that I over-implemented something already provided by Rails and that the solution I did is much less robust of what Rails already provides.

I tried to include the Rails method this way.

```
# config/initializers/tus.rb
Tus::Server.before 
   extend ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods
   authenticate_with_http_token { |token| User.find_by(token: token) }
end
```

But ended up with this error.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `authorization' for #<Tus::Server::RodaRequest:0x00007f9fe3b48450>
```

The roda request does not understands the `ActionDispatch::Request#authorization` called [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb#L458). I got stuck here as I don't understand how it may be possible to add ActionDispatch methods in the `RodaRequest` object.

I may be missing something obvious but so far I'm not seeing it.

Am I missing something more fundamental to get the `authenticate_with_http_token` method working inside the `Tus::Server` hook?

Comment: you might get other errors, but maybe patch on the `authorization` method? View the source here https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Request/authorization